# Live Updates with RESTful Service

Tags: rest

I would like to change my architecture to use RESTful service, but I'd also like the data to be live.  My REST service sits on a shared database.  I have a ListView that is populated from the REST Get verb.  If someone adds a customer to the database, I'd like the ListView to reflect that change without the user having to refresh the view.  Is this possible with REST?

Comment: You might want to research using WebSockets https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible with REST. What you can do with REST without the user refreshing the view is to have the client make frequent calls to your endpoint to check for updates.